# parse json data from url by android app

Tags: android, json, parsing, url

I'm trying to parse json from a url.
I successed to parse from one url, so I copied the json file and uploaded to my domain(diffrent url) but now I can't get any data from the json.
I havn't chaned the code in the android app except of the url.
Please Help.

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .detectAll()
    .penaltyLog()
    .build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    TextView wid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);


    JSONObject json = null;
    String str = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("My Url~");

    try {
        response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
        str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(1>0)
        tv.setText(str);
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
        json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);


        wid.setText(json.getString("id"));
        name.setText(json.getString("title"));
        url.setText(json.getString("description"));


    } catch ( JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();                
    }
```

when I print str I see all the text from the JSON file, but when I try to use getJSONObject I don't get any of the data from the JSON file.

Comment: You get back a JSON response for sure?

Comment: str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without seeing your code and the JSON data you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

1. Put Your JSON [here](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/) (or use similar JSON2POJO mapping) to generate Object from your JSON
2. Create new Java class from output of step 1 (MyClass.java)
3. Once Your JSON is fetched to your "str" variable, use e.g [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to deserialize it:

   Gson gson = new Gson();

   MyClass obj = gson.fromJson(str, MyClass.class);
4. Then you can use:

   obj.getWhatEverYouWant();

to access your data. It's much better, than parse JSON manually.

Also you should consider using RETROFIT or OKHTTP to sending your http requests.